# NIntegrate over 2D region failed. Simple integrand. Complicated region

Tags: numerical-integration, regions

The integrand is simply a Gaussian curve over one of the variables

```
PDFTheta[the_] := PDF[ NormalDistribution [0, DeltaTheta/2], the]
```

The region of integration is defined through quite a complex condition

```
Boole[(Abs[the - ArcTan[l/r]] <= ArcTan[(dF1)/Sqrt[l^2 + r^2]])]
```

Altogether gives a result that takes a long time to evaluate, and the shape wrt the variable `l` is not smooth.

```
dF1 = 0.00021; DeltaTheta = 0.0015; Deltar = 10;

foo[l_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  PDFTheta[the]*
   Boole[(Abs[the - ArcTan[l/r]] <= ArcTan[(dF1)/Sqrt[l^2 + r^2]])], {r, 0, Deltar}, {the, -DeltaTheta, DeltaTheta}]
```

[image]

These 2 errors appear:

```
NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

NIntegrate::eincr: ...
```

I tried: (1) changing to `LocalAdaptive`; (2) increasing `WorkingPrecision`; (3) changing the units (posted formulas are after the change); without success. The only thing left according to the error would be a "highly oscillatory integrand" which is not...

Any idea of possible cause or potential solution would already be very useful. Thank you.

**EDIT**
As you can see, the integration region has a non trivial shape, but it varies smoothly with `l`.

```
RegionPlot[{(Abs[the - ArcTan[l/r]] <= ArcTan[(dF1)/Sqrt[l^2 + r^2]]) /. l -> 0.0001,
(Abs[the - ArcTan[l/r]] <= ArcTan[(dF1)/Sqrt[l^2 + r^2]]) /. l -> 0.001,
(Abs[the - ArcTan[l/r]] <= ArcTan[(dF1)/Sqrt[l^2 + r^2]]) /. l -> 0.004}, 
{r, 0, Deltar}, {the, -DeltaTheta, DeltaTheta}, PlotPoints -> 80]
```

[image]

**EDIT 2**

I have done some advancements by changing to MonteCarlo method. However it is still not good and it takes a very long time evaluate.

```
foo[l_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  PDFTheta[the]*Boole[(RealAbs[the - ArcTan[l/r]] <= ArcTan[(dF1)/Sqrt[l^2 + r^2]])], {r, 0, Deltar}, {the, -DeltaTheta, DeltaTheta}, 
  Method -> {"QuasiMonteCarlo", "MaxPoints" -> 10^6}, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 5, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

[image]

Comment: `foo[l_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  PDFTheta[the]*
   Boole[(RealAbs[the - ArcTan[l/r]] <= 
      ArcTan[(dF1)/Sqrt[l^2 + r^2]])], {r, 0, 
   Deltar}, {the, -DeltaTheta, DeltaTheta}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive",
   AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 5];Plot[foo[x], {x, 0, 0.1}, PlotPoints -> 40]` draws `0` on the whole interval without any error communication.

Comment: @user64494 thank you for the comment. It is expected to be zero for x>0.005. This modification gives the same behavior when plotted with 
`LogLinearPlot[foo[x], {x, 0.0001, 0.020}, PlotPoints -> 5,  MaxRecursion -> 1]`.

Comment: `Plot[foo[x], {x, 0, 0.0001}, PlotPoints -> 40, PlotStyle -> Thick]` produces `0` on the whole interval without any error communication too.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a general answer. But it works for the problem at hand.

Since the integrand is simple enough (a Gaussian) it can be integrated over the variable `the` analytically. The integral over `r` is done afterwards numerically, with the default `NIntegrate` configuration.

```
Clear[PDFTheta]
PDFTheta[the_] := PDF[ NormalDistribution [0, DeltaTheta/2], the]
theLimUp[r_] := ArcTan[l/r] + ArcTan[(dF1)/Sqrt[l^2 + r^2]]
theLimDown[r_] := ArcTan[l/r] - ArcTan[(dF1)/Sqrt[l^2 + r^2]]
intThe = Integrate[PDFTheta[the], {the, theLimDown[r], theLimUp[r]}]
foo[lv_] := NIntegrate[intThe /. l -> lv, {r, 0, Deltar}]
```

Smooth and nice:

[image]

Comment: Can't reproduce it: `foo[l_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  PDFTheta[the]*Boole[(RealAbs[the - ArcTan[l/r]] <= ArcTan[(dF1)/Sqrt[l^2 + r^2]])], {r, 0, Deltar}, {the, -DeltaTheta, DeltaTheta}, 
  Method -> {"QuasiMonteCarlo", "MaxPoints" -> 10^6}, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 5, WorkingPrecision -> 20];Plot[foo[x], {x, 0, 0.1}, PlotPoints -> 40, PlotStyle -> Thick]` still draws `0` as well as `Plot[foo[x], {x, 0, 0.01}, PlotPoints -> 40, PlotStyle -> Thick]`.

Comment: Hi @user64494 . Thank you for your interest, honestly, this is worrisome if the result is different in my machine than in yours.

This for me is not zero:

`dF1 = 0.00021; DeltaTheta = 0.0015; Deltar = 10;
PDFTheta[the_] := PDF[ NormalDistribution [0, DeltaTheta/2], the];

[copy-paste your function in the comment];

Plot[foo[x], {x, 0, 0.1}, PlotPoints -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 1, 
 PlotStyle -> Thick]`-

`PlotPoints->40` would take forever in my computer. 

However, **the MonteCarlo method is not the solution** . Your comment is placed in response to the analytical method.

Comment: `RegionPlot[{(RealAbs[the - ArcTan[l/r]] <= 
     ArcTan[(dF1)/Sqrt[l^2 + r^2]]) /. 
   l -> 0.0001, (RealAbs[the - ArcTan[l/r]] <= 
     ArcTan[(dF1)/Sqrt[l^2 + r^2]]) /. 
   l -> 0.001, (RealAbs[the - ArcTan[l/r]] <= 
     ArcTan[(dF1)/Sqrt[l^2 + r^2]]) /. l -> 0.004}, {r, 0, 
  Deltar}, {the, -DeltaTheta, DeltaTheta}, PlotPoints -> 80]`  performs the same result that presented by you. The executed codes on demand through Dropbox.